# Font size of figures and table captions

Tags: floats, captions, fontsize

I need my figure and table captions to be of font size 8pt, how do I achieve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using one of the standard classes (`book`, `report`, `article`) or a class compatible with the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package, then you can declare your default font specification using `\DeclareCaptionFont` and then use this new declaration in `\captionsetup`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionFont{mysize}{\fontsize{8}{9.6}\selectfont}
\captionsetup{font=mysize}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
A
\caption{The caption of the figure will be typeset using \texttt{8pt} font size}
\end{figure}
Regular text.

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: what is the 9.6 that you have next to 8?

Comment: @tilaprimera the value for the baselineskip (the vertical separation between two consecutive lines).